# Trouble setting PHP variable in if statement

Tags: php, ajax

I have an Ajax call to create an image gallery. There is a combo box to set the number of images per page, and pagination to navigate through the pages. It's working fine, except that if a person is on the last page, and they increase the number of images per page, it reloads to the current page number. This is a problem because there are now less pages and so the page is blank. In other words, you end up on `page 7 of 5` for instance.

I reckon the problem is in the PHP as that is where the number of pages is calculated. I've thought out an `if` statement to deal with this:

```
if ($page > $no_of_paginations) {
 $page = $no_of_paginations;
}
```

However, I don't know where to place this. The reason being, `$page` needs to be defined *before* the mysql_query, but `$no_of_paginations` is defined *after* the query.

Any thoughts on how I can make this functional?

I'll post the pertinent code below:

```
<?php
$page = 0;
if(isset($_GET['page'])){
$page = (int) $_GET['page'];
}
$cur_page = $page;
$page -= 1;
if((int) $_GET['imgs'] > 0){ 
    $per_page = (int) $_GET['imgs']; 
} else { 
    $per_page = 16; 
}
$start = $per_page * $page;

include"db.php";

$query_pag_data = "SELECT `imgURL`,`imgTitle` FROM `images` ".
"ORDER BY `imgDate` DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page";

$result_pag_data = mysql_query($query_pag_data) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());

echo "<ul class='new_arrivals_gallery'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_pag_data)) { 
    echo "<li><a target='_blank' href='new_arrivals_img/".$row['imgURL']."' class='gallery' title='".$row['imgTitle']."'><img src='new_arrivals_img/thumbnails/".$row['imgURL']."'></a></li>";
  }
echo "</ul>";   


/* --------------------------------------------- */
$query_pag_num = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM images";
$result_pag_num = mysql_query($query_pag_num);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_num);
$count = $row['count'];
$no_of_paginations = ceil($count / $per_page);
?>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are currently doing it, there would be no problem with moving the last section to above the main query.

A better way to find the total records with MySQL is to use the [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) keyword on your main query (so here it is `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS imgURL, imgTitle FROM images WHERE etc`) then you can query `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` and just get the number of records found in the last query.  As well as being faster and more efficient, this avoids a race condition when records are added between the two queries.

However, in this case you should probably just do the two current queries in the reverse order as your only other option is to check at the end and repeat if necessary.

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions. Changing the query destroyed my pagination, and I have a feeling is has to do with the code I did not include that controls the pagination. I also tried what your second suggestion, and there was no problem under I placed my if statement. Perhaps my statement is wrong somehow? I'm pretty new to PHP.

Comment: You need to give more information about what happened, what is your output after your changes?

Comment: I was able to get it to work by reversing the order of the two queries and their respective variables. Am I right to surmise that since I did this, I can't use the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`? I'm assuming this as `$query_pag_num` is now defined *before* `$query_pag_data`.

Comment: That's right: you need to do the query first to populate the variable found_rows() returns

Answer (score 1):

You should use query:

```
$query_pag_data = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `imgURL`,`imgTitle` FROM `images` ".
"ORDER BY `imgDate` DESC LIMIT $start, $per_page";
```

And instead of

```
$query_pag_num = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM images";
```

use

```
$query_pag_num = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS()";
```

Comment: And use the `if` statement I already put together? Where would I place the `if` statement in your opinion?

Comment: Changing the query as you suggested has destroyed my pagination. Only the Combo Box now works. Perhaps it has something to do with the PHP I did not show you.

Comment: Try to use instead of $row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_num);
$count = $row['count']; - $count = mysql_fetch_field($result_pag_num);

Comment: It seems that my solution doesn't solve your problem. You can look at http://www.slideshare.net/suratbhati/efficient-pagination-using-mysql-6187107 an try to choose the best variant.

Answer (score 0):

If you do the "SELECT COUNT(*) ..." query earlier in the script (at least before the other query), you will have $no_of_paginations earlier, and can use it to clamp $page to the correct range.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and there was no problem under I placed my `if` statement. Perhaps my statement is wrong somehow? I'm pretty new to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just have to bite the bullet and do a query twice. Accept the user-provided "I want page X" value, and try to get that particular page. If it ends up being past the end of the available data, you can either say "hey, wait... that ain't right" and abort, or redo the loop and default to the last available page.

```
while(true) {
     $sql = "select sql_calc_found_rows .... limit $X,$Y";
     $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

     $sql = "select found_rows();"; // retrieve the sql_calc_found_rows_value
     $res2 = mysql_query($sql);

     $row = mysql_fetch_array($res2);
     $total_rows = $row[0];

     if ($total_rows < $requested_row) {
        ... redo the loop and request last possible page ...
     } else {
        break;
     }
}
```

details on found_rows() function [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).

Comment: Gosh, I get what you're explaining... kind of. But with the code, how do I 'redo the loop' as you suggested? Also, I haven't tried this out yet, but others have suggested that I change my query to include `sql_calc_found_rows` and it destroys my pagination. Could this work with my existing queries the way they are?

Comment: sql_calc shouldn't change anything. it just makes mysql calculate how many rows WOULD have been returned by the query, if it wasn't for the limit clause. it doesn't change actual query results at all. As for the redo bit, just replicate your query setup bits where you calculate the limits to being with, but do it was if the user had requested the last page for real (e.g. change $page to 5 instead of the 7 or whatever they requested and re-run the query with the new limit.